# ios - Overlapping table views and scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am writing a simple iphone app. I have:
 - A search bar at the top
 - A table view below that

I've got another table view which gets displayed under the search bar once the user starts typing, showing suggestions for what they might mean. When shown this table view overlaps with the main table view mentioned above.

The problem I have is that I cant scroll the table view showing suggestions. When I try to it scrolls the table view it's overlapping instead.

Any thoughts on how to make the suggestions table view scroll? I could be doing something silly - I'm very new to iphone programming.

Thanks!

Comment: you should post some code specially your tableview delegate methods for us to see what you are really upto....

Comment: Thanks - worked out what was confusing things - see post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I was adding the table view holding the suggestions to the search bar, adding it to the search bar's parent seems to have fixed it. I.e:

```
[[searchBar superview] addSubview:tableView];
```

I assume the logic is that I can only receive touch events that overlap with my views parent area.